# Solve this equation 3x3 using Gauss-Jordan

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have this problem:

With this system, determine the values of $K$ to the system have:

a) One only solution
b) Don`t have solution
c) Infinite solutions

$x-3z=-3$

$2x+Ky-z=-2$

$x+2y+Kz=1$

How do I solve that system?, I already know the answer but I haven't could reach it.

Thank you!

Comment: Set up an augmented matrix and reduce in the usual way.  There is nothing special about $K$, it is just a number and you can add it, subtract it etc like any other number.

Answer (score 2):

First, we convert the system of equations to an [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) (which is essentially just another way of writing the system of equations):

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -3 & -3 \\
2 & K & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & K & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].
$$

We can think of $K$ as some number that we don't happen to know.  We apply [row operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations) until we get the matrix in [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) (this is referred to as [Gauss-Jordan Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)).

Along the way, we might need to apply a row operation which amounts to dividing a row by $K$ (or some function of $K$).  We can only do this if $K \neq 0$.  We will therefore need to keep track of these assumptions, and resolve these cases separately.

Likely, most of the time, we'll reach a reduced row echelon form like the following:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & ??? \\
0 & 1 & 0 & ??? \\
0 & 0 & 1 & ??? \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
and the values where the question marks determine the $x,y,z$-values, and thus gives a unique solution.

It might happen (for some values of $K$) that we reach a reduced row echelon form like:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & ??? \\
0 & 1 & 0 & ??? \\
\color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue}{\neq 0} \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
which would imply no solutions (i.e., the system is inconsistent).

If, for some value of $K$, the system is consistent (i.e., there are solutions) and the reduced row echelon form has a row of zeros, there will be infinitely many solutions.  E.g., it could look like
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & ??? \\
0 & 1 & 1 & ??? \\
\color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\end{array}\right].
$$

So your task is to perform the row operations to the augmented matrix, and determine which values of $K$ give rise to which type of reduced row echelon form.

(If doing this by hand, it's more likely than not that arithmetic errors arise; so try to keep on top of these.)

Comment: Great answer! I wish people asking questions would at least take the time to upvote answers that show a lot of time and energy spent.